# DATEDIF in Workflow

Tags: 2010, workflow, date-time

Is it possible to use `DATEIF` inside a workflow? Right now I have:

```
=DATEDIF(TODAY(),[Expiration Date],"D")
```

Is this possible inside a workflow `if`? is there a certain benefit to it? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can incorporate that same logic inside a workflow, but it will not be in that format. The way it will look in a SharePoint Designer workflow will use the "Find interval between two Dates" action:

```
Find days between CurrentItem:Created and Today (Output to Variable:DifferenceVariableinDays)
```